# Question On "Get"

Tags: expressions

1.Let's say a woman is drowning in a lake and a man who happens to notice her drowning has thrown away a rope towards her and he says **"Get the rope!"**.

In this situation, can this sentence **"Get the rope"** mean the same thing as **"hold or take the rope"** ?

2.Let's say the car doors are open and I say **"get the car doors!"** to my son.

In this situation, can this sentence **"get the car doors!"** mean the same thing as **"close the car doors!"** ?

3.Let's say a friend poor at math asks me how to solve a mathematical problem, and after a while, the friend says **"Have you got the problem?"** or **"You get the problem"**?

In this situation, can these sentences **"Have you got the problem?"** and **"You get the problem"** mean **"Have you understood the problem"** and **"You understand the problem"**?

4.Let's say your mom has made you cookies and she says **"get some cookies!"**.

In this situation, can this sentence **"get some cookies"** mean **"eat some cookies!"** ?

5.Let's say your mom notices your room is so dirty and she says **"get your room!"**

In this situation, can this sentence **"get your room"** mean **"clean your room"** ?

6.Let's say a comrade puts down his gun on the ground while an enemy is approaching and I say to the comrade **"get your gun now!"**.

In this situation, can this sentence **"get your gun"** mean **"take or hole your gun"** ?

7.Let's say a comrade, holding his gun, is not aiming his gun at enemies approaching, and I say to the comrade "get your gun right now!"

In this situation, can this sentence **"get your gun right now!"** mean **"aim your gun right now!"** ?

8.Let's say after having dinner, my mom tells me to **"get the dishes"**.

In this situation, can this sentence **"get dishes"** mean **"wash the dishes"** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "Take", not "hold".
2. Yes.
3. Yes.
4. No. "Take", not "eat".
5. No.
6. "Take", not "hol[d]".
7. No.
8. "Get *the* dishes", yes. Probably.

"Get" directly means "take". It also means "understand", and it can also mean "handle/take care of/sort out the situation".

Your comrade might say "There's the enemy! Get your gun, and get them! Get it?"

By the way, the difference between 5 and 8 is context. "Get the dishes" might sound a bit strange, but I could infer that they're asking me to clean the dirty dishes rather than take them, because that's the most obvious thing to do with dirty dishes. I wouldn't know what "get your room" would mean, because there's nothing obvious that you do with a room.